# Understanding JavaScript anonymous functions, variables, and scoping

Tags: javascript, jquery

We're trying to understand variable scoping inside JavaScript anonymous functions.

This code only needs to work inside Webkit browsers since it's for a PhoneGap app.

Given the code block below, will the arguments to **setTimeout** always be the same for each item in **all_packs**, or will the changing value of **pack_name** (since it changes on each iteration of the jQuery loop) affect the arguments? In other words, each new row should be associated with a different item in **all_packs**. Is this the correct way to use anonymous functions, or will some rows end up referencing the same name?

We can't use **this.name** inside the **tap** anonymous function because **this** will no longer refer to the item inside **all_packs**. As a result, we first stashed the name inside **pack_name**.

Assume **TAP_DELAY** is a constant set elsewhere, **start_work** is a valid function, and **all_packs** is an array of objects.

```
    // Load each pack
    $( all_packs ).each( function(index) {              
            // Set vars
            var pack_name = this.name;
            var row = $( '#templates .row' ).clone( true );

        // Append new row
        $( '#test' ).append( row );

            // Valid pack?
            if ( this.valid ) {             
                // Configure for tap
                row.on( 'tap', function() {
                                setTimeout( start_work, TAP_DELAY, pack_name );             
                });
            } else {
                            setTimeout( start_work, TAP_DELAY, this.name );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Every "pack_name" will be distinct; there's a new closure formed upon each invocation of the `.each()` callback function.

Comment: Also, Internet Explorer doesn't allow extra arguments to `setTimeout`. You could use `.bind()` to wrap your "start_work" function with an additional argument however.

Comment: Thanks, @Pointy. This is only for use inside a Webkit browser.

Comment: @Pointy, your answer seems to conflict with jfriend00's answer unless we're misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yes, but I think jfriend00 is confused. A jQuery `.each()` "loop" is not the same as a `for` loop.

Comment: OK, then you have the right answer and not jfriend00. @Pointy, can you post an answer and explanation so you can earn the points?